# Access Border Property of Point of Radar Chart

Tags: vba, excel

In Excel VBA, I am able to access Each Point of RadarChart using

```
ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).Points(1).Select
```

and I am apply an image using

```
With Selection
    .MarkerStyle = -4147
    .MarkerSize = 5
End With
With Selection.Format.Fill
    .Visible = msoTrue
    .UserPicture FilePath + "Red.PNG"
End With
```

The Problem is this marker ends up with a Border
If I record a Macro to do the change and see code

```
Selection.Format.Line.Visible = msoFalse
```

is recorded, but if the same is run it causes the series line to disappear.

Can somebody help me with code to turn off the border.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use `.MarkerForegroundColorIndex = xlColorIndexNone`

See this example

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    Dim sc As Series, dp As Point
    Dim FilePath As String

    FilePath = "C:\"

    Set sc = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(1).Chart.SeriesCollection(1)

    With sc
        .MarkerStyle = -4147
        .MarkerSize = 5

        For Each dp In sc.Points
            dp.MarkerForegroundColorIndex = xlColorIndexNone
        Next

        With .Format.Fill
            .Visible = msoTrue
            .UserPicture FilePath + "Red.PNG"
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

**BEFORE**

[image]

**AFTER**

[image]

Comment: On a side note If i create a new note in Excel 2013 the Axis Lines don't show up, even if I set it to Solid, This doesn't happen on Charts created in earlier version. Do you have any Idea on this